# The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception when try to embed Awesomium dlls

Tags: c#, awesomium, fody-costura

I'm Trying to embed Awesomium into my project executable file. In the documentation of Awesomium, they said that set the target platform of your project to `X86`. Is that mean there is only `Unmanaged32Assemblies` available?

I add this line to `FodyWeaver.xml` file:

```
<Costura Unmanaged32Assemblies='Awesomium.Core|Awesomium.Windows.Forms'/>
```

But I got an exception that says:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.
```

I also try tried this:

```
<Costura 
    Unmanaged32Assemblies='Awesomium.Core|Awesomium.Windows.Forms' 
    Unmanaged64Assemblies='Awesomium.Core|Awesomium.Windows.Forms' />
```

But exactly same exception was thrown.

**Update**

Also Tried this:

```
<Costura 
    Unmanaged32Assemblies='awesomium' 
    Unmanaged64Assemblies='awesomium'/>
```

and this:

```
<Costura 
    Unmanaged32Assemblies='awesomium'/>
```

It's make my exe file about 4 MB bigger, but again same exception was thrown

Comment: Try debugging Costura - [Debugging](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/wiki/Debugging). Otherwise I recommend not using Costura.

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly you're trying to embed using `Unmanaged32Assemblies` is not a mixed-mode assembly, then that method won't work.

Instead, try adding something like this to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="..\packages\path\to\awesomium.dll">
    <LogicalName>costura32.%(Filename)%(Extension)</LogicalName>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Costura will find this resource at load time and extract it to a temporary directory so that your app will be able to find/load it.